# SQL Select statement to get all records that contains one or more values in a string

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I am stuck with this problem:

I made 3 custom `meta_key` in `wp_postmeta`. Now I have to select all the records that contain in the column `meta_value`, one or more words, from a string I provide.

This is the SQL I wrote, but it's not giving me back any results, even if I have one word matching the **REGEX**.

```
 SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE
 meta_key = 'packaging_attributes'
 AND
 meta_key = 'properties_attributes'
 AND
 meta_key = 'tech_functions_attributes'
 AND
 meta_value REGEXP 'chased-floor|chased-wall-plasterboard|alarm-en|0-22|0-220-75|15|25'
```

This is the screenshot from the db:[image]

As you can see in row **1008** I have **chased-wall-plasterboard**, that should match the above select, and give me back **39** as result. But it's not working.

If I remove the three `meta_key = column_name` I am going to get tons of results but not the **39**.

Comment: You should use OR not AND.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that what you really want are meta posts having records with all 3 meta values in the current `WHERE` clause.  If so, then aggregation is one approach:

```sql
SELECT post_id
FROM wp_postmeta
WHERE meta_key IN ('packaging_attributes', 'properties_attributes', 'tech_functions_attributes') AND
      meta_value REGEXP 'chased-floor|chased-wall-plasterboard|alarm-en|0-22|0-220-75|15|25'
GROUP BY post_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT meta_key) = 3;
```

It is not clear whether the restriction on `meta_value` really belongs there.

Comment: Thanks Tim, it worked like a charm. I only had to remove the HAVING COUNT(...), and it worked by giving me back the id 39

Comment: @d0t_m ... but removing the `HAVING` clause changes the query.  What is the exact output you really wanted to see?

Comment: For example, if I have 30 products that have into ('packaging_attributes', 'properties_attributes', 'tech_functions_attributes') at least one word listed into the REGEX, I expect to get back a list of IDs. 

So if in those 30, 22 of them have  into ```meta_value``` the REGEX **chased-wall-plasterboard**, I want those 22 IDs, leaving out the orthers.

Answer (score 0):

You should use OR operation to gather all 4 rows.

```
 SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE
 meta_key = 'packaging_attributes'
 OR
 meta_key = 'properties_attributes'
 OR
 meta_key = 'tech_functions_attributes'
 OR
 meta_value REGEXP 'chased-floor|chased-wall-plasterboard|alarm-en|0-22|0-220-75|15|25'
```